# Inputting an esc char stores a decimal value of 10, when It should be showing a value of 27

Tags: c, windows, ascii, scanf, getchar

when I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int ESC;
    ESC = getchar();
    printf("\n%d", ESC);
}
```

it prints a value of '10', but the ascii table states it should have a value of '27'. I've tried this using scanf as well but got the same result. What is going on?

Comment: ESC has not been read by `getchar()`. What you're seeing is the linefeed when you pressed RETURN after having pressed ESC.

Comment: Ah, so how can I read the 'ESC' character?

Comment: The type of `ESC` should be `int` as `getchar()` returns `int`. Press 'ESC' and then hit enter. That should ensure 'ESC' is read before the 'Return'.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: We need more details on your operating system/terminal type you're using/whatever to have any hope of telling you why this is happening. Most likely the esc keypress is never making it to your program.

Comment: You are using `void main()`, so I guess that you are under Turbo C, `getch` from `conio.h` is what you are looking for.

Comment: That did it keine, thank you.

Comment: @J.Yonathan: You are welcome, but note that `getch` returns an `int` (not a `char`)

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use the Library `#include <conio.h>`, and then use the `getch()` function, it works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int ESC;
    ESC = getch();
    printf("%d", ESC);
}
```

Comment: FYI with Windows and MSVC your original program does return `10` when `Esc` is entered but curiously if you enter `Ctrl+[` which should be the equivalent it outputs the expected `27`. So my guess is that the *key* is ignored, rather than its resulting value, though there is nothing about that in the MS man page for `getchar`.

Comment: You should not use `conio.h`. It's a non-standard header from very old compilers like Borland's compilers for DOS. Learning non-standard features from a compiler that's been obsolete for 20 years is not especially useful.